# How can I find the most similar row from other dataset in Python?

Tags: python

I would like to find the top 1 similar row between two data frames. My tables dont match the ID but I would like to compare the values between three columns (closest amount and dates). The tables are as below:

Df1

| ID | Amount | Ocurred Date | Sale Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | $100 | 02/20/2023 | 02/20/2022 |
| 2 | $20 | 01/20/2023 | 08/19/2022 |

Df2

| ID2 | Amount | Ocurred Date | Sale Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 9 | $98 | 02/20/2023 | 02/21/2022 |
| 8 | $19 | 01/19/2023 | 08/23/2022 |

Output expected:

| ID | ID2 |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 9 |
| 2 | 8 |

Answer (score 0):

Well, it depends on your distance metric but a very basic implementation of this is to loop over the rows of each df calculate distance and set the results in a result df. Here i am only comparing prices but you can modify calculate distance to fit your needs:

```py
def calculate_distance(row1, row2):
    return abs(int(row1["Amount"][1:]) - int(row2["Amount"][1:]))

result = pd.DataFrame(columns=["ID", "ID2"])
for i, row1 in df1.iterrows():
    smallest_distance = float("inf")
    id_with_smallest_distance = ""

    for j, row2 in df2.iterrows():
        distance = calculate_distance(row1, row2)
        if distance < smallest_distance:
            smallest_distance = distance
            id_with_smallest_distance = row2["ID2"]
    
    result.loc[i] = row1["ID"], id_with_smallest_distance
```